# i don't understand the utility of default values in state machine

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to understand state machine in VHDL for detecting the edge on a signal in VHDL. in next state I dont understand why we put the:
"next_etat<= reg_etat" because I think it could work without any problem even without it .
I'd would what are the default value of reg_etat and next_etat when we have just run the program because their is no real default value like in c for example int var=0;

```
entity machine_etat is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        rst : in STD_LOGIC;
        entree : in STD_LOGIC;
        tc : out STD_LOGIC);
end machine_etat;

architecture architecture_machine_etat of machine_etat is
type T_etat is (idle,edge,one);
signal next_etat, reg_etat : T_etat;
begin

registre_etat: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if rst = ’1’ then
            reg_etat <= idle;
        else
            reg_etat <= next_etat;
        end if;
    end if;
end process registre_etat;

tc <= ’1’ when reg_etat = edge else ’0’;

etat_suivant: process(reg_etat,entree)
begin
next_etat <= reg_etat;-- defaults values here i dont see their purpose
case reg_etat is
    when idle =>
        if entree =’1’ then
            next_etat <= edge;
        end if;
    when edge =>
        next_etat <= one;
    when one =>
        if entree =’0’ then
            next_etat <= idle;
        end if;
    end case;
end process etat_suivant;
end architecture_machine_etat;
```

Comment: Sorry i mean "because it could work without any problem even without it ".
Could you please explain why the FSM will not progress because for me the reg_etat is updated in registre_etat process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't assign `next_etat` (pardon my French) in all situations, logical synthesis will infer a latch to remember it's state. A latch is something you don't want, as it is very sensitive to digital logic latencies and might become metastable: also something you don't want.

HDL programming significantly differs from CPU programming.

Comment: I see thank you, just to be sure i fully understood, the latch will affect next_etat only when next_etat is not assigned in the blocek ?
as for default value of reg_etat if we don't assigned reset to 1 nothing will happen right ?

Comment: @Ryan of there is any situation in which next_etat is not assigned a value within the process evaluation, it will mean that it should keep it's old value. But since that is not triggered by a clock (which would infer a clocked memory element called a register), a latch would be inferred.

Comment: @ryan for the second question. No, because the*_etats are of the type T_etat, their default value will be the first possibility of that type: idle in this case.

Comment: "Etats" spelled backward gives "state".... Hmmmm, coincidence or not....

Comment: haha I have not noticed that, it is almost true except that Etats is in plural and state is not.
I understand now. Thank you very much !